# LMS error no operator = matches these operands

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, assignment-operator

So for practice purposes I am creating a library management system using composition, to understand and practice the concept of composition.so i have a book class and a user class. i am composing a pointer of book class in the user class. i am using dma (dynamic memory allocation) for the add function.but i am getting this error that i am unable to debug.

**Error (active)    E0349   no operator "=" matches these operands  PRAcTice**

here's the whole code for understanding

```
#ifndef LMS_H
#define LMS_H

#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class book {
  private:
    string bname;
  int ISBN;
  string author;
  string publisher;
  public:
    book(string n = " ", int i = 0, string a = " ", string p = " ") {
      bname = n;
      ISBN = i;
      author = a;
      publisher = p;
    }

  void setbname(string a) {
    bname = a;
  }
  string getbname() {
    return bname;
  }
  void setisbn(int b) {
    ISBN = b;
  }
  int getisbn() {
    return ISBN;
  }
  void setauthor(string c) {
    author = c;
  }
  string getauthor() {
    return author;
  }
  void setpublisher(string d) {
    publisher = d;
  }
  string getpublisher() {
    return publisher;
  }

  friend ostream & operator << (ostream & COUT, book & rhs);
};

ostream & operator << (ostream & COUT, book & rhs) {
  COUT << "Book Name: " << rhs.getbname() << endl;
  COUT << "ISBN: " << rhs.getisbn() << endl;
  COUT << "Author: " << rhs.getauthor() << endl;
  COUT << "Publisher: " << rhs.getpublisher() << endl;
}

class user {
  private:
    string name;
  int id;
  string password;
  book * b;
  int bno;
  public:
    user(string m = " ", int q = 0, string n = " ", book * bx = NULL, int no = 0) {
      name = m;
      id = q;
      password = n;
      b = bx;
    }

  void setname(string a) {
    name = a;
  }
  string getbname() {
    return name;
  }
  void setid(int b) {
    id = b;
  }
  int getid() {
    return id;
  }
  void setpassword(string c) {
    password = c;
  }
  string getpassword() {
    return password;
  }
  void setbno(int d) {
    bno = d;
  }
  int getisbn() {
    return bno;
  }

  void setbook(book a[]) {
    b = new book[bno];
    for (int i = 0; i < bno; i++) {
      b[i].setbname(a[i].getbname());
      b[i].setisbn(a[i].getisbn());
      b[i].setauthor(a[i].getauthor());
      b[i].setpublisher(a[i].getpublisher());
    }
  }
  book * getbook() {
    return b;
  }

  book * add(book b) {
    b = new book[bno + 1];

  }

};

#endif // !"LMS_H"
```

Comment: Unrelated: You're missing a return statement inside `operator<<` and inside `add` as well.

Comment: Rather than posting all the code, you should [edit] your question down to a [mcve]. For instance, your `getid()` function is probably unrelated to the error, so you shouldn't make answerers wade through it to get to the important bits.

Comment: `book* add(book b) { b = new book[bno + 1]; }` — You are assigning a pointer to the non-pointer object `b` of type `book`. (Also, the `return` statement is missing in this function.)

Comment: @FatimaKhan *"found the error thanks"* -- good. Your next step should be to either accept an answer (if it adequately answers your question) or post [your own answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (If there was not an upvoted answer, a third option would have been to delete the question, but that should only be done if the question has no value to future visitors.) Accepting an answer is how to indicate on this site that an issue is resolved, not editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the object `b` on the left hand side of the assignment `b = new book[bno + 1];` is of type `book` while the object on the right hand side is of type `book*`.

```
//---v----------------------->type of object b is book
     b = new book[bno + 1];
//-------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----type of the resulting object on rhs is book*
```

That is there is a mismatch in the type on the left hand side and right hand side of the assignment and since there is no overloaded `operator=` that has parameter of type `book` and `book*` you get the mentioned error.

---

Additionally you're missing return statements inside `operator<<` and inside `add`.